# Unable to pass data from parent to child component aura

Tags: apex, aura, parent, aura-method

I'm working in a lightning aura component and I'm trying to pass variables from parent to child but it's showing undefined. If I display it in logs before passing it to the child component variables have values but the child is showing as undefined.I'm breaking my head to fix this

Parent component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="QuarterStart" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="QuarterEnd" type="String"/>
    <c:Sales_VP_Rollup aura:id="salesvpRollup"></c:Sales_VP_Rollup>
</aura:component>
```

Parent Controller:

```
filterCommissions: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var changeRadioButton = cmp.get("v.Radiobuttonvalue");
    if (changeRadioButton == 'option2') {
        var quarterType = cmp.find("selectmonth").get("v.value");
        if (quarterType == 'Previous FQ') {
            cmp.set("v.QuarterStart", "LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER");
            cmp.set("v.QuarterEnd", null);
            console.log("QuarterStart_date_parent" + cmp.get("v.QuarterStart"));
            cmp.find('salesvpRollup').fetchSalesVPbyQuarter(cmp.get("v.QuarterStart"), cmp.get("v.QuarterEnd"));
        }
    }
```

Child component:

```
<aura:component controller="AllCommissions">
    <aura:method name="fetchSalesVPbyQuarter" action="{!c.fetchSalesVPcommissionsbyQuarter}" description="fetch AE vp commissions by date">
        <aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" default="true"/>    
        <aura:attribute name="rowNumberOffset" type="Integer" default="10"/>
        <aura:attribute name="QuarterStart" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="QuarterEnd" type="String" />
    </aura:method>
```

Child Controller:

```
fetchSalesVPcommissionsbyQuarter: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    //cmp.set("v.showSpinner", true);
    var params = event.getParam('arguments');
    if (params) {
        var quarterstart = params.QuarterStart;
        var quarterend = params.QuarterEnd;
    }
    console.log("Start_Date_Fired" + quarterstart);
    //helper.fetchAEVPRollupCommissions(cmp, event, helper, quarterstart, quarterend);
}
```

console logs:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `aura:method` has four arguments it can take: `showRowNumberColumn`, `rowNumberOffset`, `QuarterStart` and `QuarterEnd`.

When you call the method in your parent controller, you need to specify values for these arguments *in that order*.

For example:

```
cmp.find('salesvpRollup').fetchSalesVPbyQuarter(showRowNumberColumn, rowNumberOffset, QuarterStart, QuarterEnd);
```

Because you have missed off the first two, you are actually setting `showRowNumberColumn` to `cmp.get("v.QuarterStart")` and `rowNumberOffset` to `cmp.get("v.QuarterEnd")`

To fix this, you can do something like:

```
cmp.find('salesvpRollup').fetchSalesVPbyQuarter(null, null, cmp.get("v.QuarterStart"), cmp.get("v.QuarterEnd"));
```

Comment: It worked like a charm fred